# mysql: using comma-separated values

Tags: mysql

I have a simple mysql table which I use as a server booking system. A user can log in to a server, if he has a valid booking for that server. A sample data might look like this:

```
+----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| server   | user           | start               | end                 |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| server01 | Alice,Bob      | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| server02 | Carlos         | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| server03 | Dan,Erin,Frank | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

To check whether user `Carlos` has a booking for `server02`, I use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 0, id FROM booking WHERE user = 'Carlos'
AND (( start < now() and end > now() ) AND server = 'server02') ;
```

But this query does not work if there are multiple (comma-separated) users. How can I check if `Alice` has booking for `server01` ?

Comment: Why do you store your data in this way?

Comment: Indeed MySQL should crash if you abuse MySQL like this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your `booking` table is in very serious (critical, severe, dire, vital, etc,) need of normalization on the `user` column, here is what you can do in the meantime...

```
SELECT 0, id FROM booking
WHERE ((start < now() and end > now())
AND server = 'server02') AND
LOCATE(',Alice,',CONCAT(',',user,',')) > 0;
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT : [Please normalize your data as Johnny000 just suggested !!!](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52497/877) Why???

You will not get any decent query performance searching by `user` in CSV format.

If you normalize `user`, your data should like this:

```
+----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| server   | user   | start               | end                 |
+----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| server01 | Alice  | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| server01 | Bob    | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| server02 | Carlos | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| server03 | Dan    | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| server03 | Erin   | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| server03 | Frank  | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
+----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

If you do the reset of the normalizing, you should get this:

## user table

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Alice  |
|  2 | Bob    |
|  3 | Carlos |
|  4 | Dan    |
|  5 | Erin   |
|  6 | Frank  |
+----+--------+
```

## server table

```
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+---------------+
|  1 | server01 |
|  2 | server02 |
|  3 | server03 |
+----+----------+
```

## booking table

```
+----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| serverid | userid | start               | end                 |
+----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1        | 1      | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 1        | 2      | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2        | 3      | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 3        | 4      | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 3        | 5      | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 3        | 6      | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2013-12-31 00:00:00 |
+----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

You could create indexes on the `booking` tables like this:

```
ALTER TABLE booking
    ADD INDEX user_server_ndx (userid,serverid),
    ADD INDEX server_user_ndx (serverid,userid),
    ADD INDEX start_end_ndx  (start,end),
    ADD INDEX end_ndx (end)
;
```

Perhaps you do not need all these indexes, but you can decide which ones are not needed.

Comment: What about the function FIND_IN_SET http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set for normalization problems like this?

Answer (score 5):

I would overthink your design and would change to something like this:

### Usertable

```
+--------+----------+
| UserID | Username |
+--------+----------+
|    1   |   PAUL   |
+--------+----------+
|    2   |   Eric   |
+--------+----------+
```

### Servertable

```
+------------+------------------+
|  ServerID  |    Servername    |
+------------+------------------+
|     1      |      Apache      |
+------------+------------------+
|     2      |      Nginx       |
+------------+------------------+
```

### Serverbooking

```
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
|   ServerID  |     UserID      |      Start    |     End     |
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
|      1      |        1        |   somedate    |   somedate  |
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
|      2      |        1        |   somedate    |   somedate  |
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
|      1      |        2        |   somedate    |   somedate  |
+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: vote up for normalization